# Combining these queries into a multi Table Join

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have multiple queries that I want to combine into a 9 table join (probably a bad idea?) to get 4 specific columns from the tables. But I'm unsure what is the best way to do this.

I want to get the `total number of genres watched by each country name.`

So the columns I want are:

`name` from the category table

`country` from the country table

and a newly created column `num_rentals integer`

[image]

https://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-sample-database/

I'm unsure how I would approach this. Should I join all the other tables into the `rental` table and perform a groupby/count to get the number of rentals for that country?

After looking through the tables I see that they all tie into each other with one attribute...such as country_id in city, city_id in address, address_id in customer, customer_id in rental

```
SELECT rental.customer_id FROM rental AS rental;

SELECT country.country FROM country AS country;

SELECT city.country_id FROM city AS city;

SELECT address.city_id FROM address AS address;

SELECT customer.address_id FROM customer AS customer;
```

What's the best way do it?

Comment: May I know which tool you used to create that diagram?

Comment: Hi, I didn't create the diagram it's from this site https://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-sample-database/. I do know lucidchart.com has a similar tool to create diagrams like this though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need something like :

```
    select category.name, country.country, count(*)
from country 
join city on country.country_id = city.city_id
join address on address.city_id = city.city_id
join customer on customer.address_id = address.address_id
join rental on rental.customer_id = customer.customer_id
join inventory on inventory.inventory_id = rental.inventory_id
join film on film.film_id = inventory.inventory_id
join film_category on film_category.film_id = film.film_id
join category on category.category_id = film_category.category_id
group by category.name, country.country
```